# Как реализовать функционал, чтобы пользователь мог убирать товары из корзины?

Tags: javascript

```js
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length-1; i++) {
    //Вешаем обработчик события клика на каждую из кнопок
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      //Создали копию карточки с товаром
      let item = products[i].cloneNode(true), 
          btn = item.querySelector('button');
          
      
      btn.textContent = 'Удалить';
      //btn.remove();
      field.appendChild(item);
      //Удаляем карточку с товаром
      products[i].remove();
      
      
      
    })
  }
```

Нужно внутри цикла повесить еще обработчик событий на btn.textContent. Как это можно сделать. Я в js новичок. Код на гите https://github.com/iSdmd/js_beginner/blob/master/mini_bag/js/script.js

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove() {
 item.remove();
let shop = document.querySelector('.shop');
shop.appendChild(products[i]);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', remove);
```